# How do I do a complete BIND9 DNS Server Configuration with a hostname?

Tags: bind

I need a complete step-by-step guide on how to produce such a server configuration.

Can anyone help-me?

Answer (score 124):

## **Complete DNS server in ubuntu server 12.**

First of all change the ip address of your server form DHCP to STATIC for this use the following command

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and add:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
# dns-nameservers
```

Restart networking daemons

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Before configuring a DNS server in linux Ubuntu you have to make domain name first and then you will proceed. First you will check your hostname command for this is

```
sudo nano /etc/hostname

 nefitari
```

(This is my Ubuntu server hostname yours might be different .You can change this according to your need)

Now after hostname, you have to make domain name for your server. Say servername.domain.com it is better practice that whenever you are configuring server for home use or so, do not use .com but .hom or .net or whatever you like. Give the below command

```
  sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

add if it does not have it:

```
  127.0.0.1   localhost

  192.168.1.5     nefitari.autun.hom    nefitari
```

In my file 127.0.0.1 is for localhost and I have changed the second IP address 127.0.1.1 with my server IP that is 192.168.1.5 now I enter my domain name having my hostname **nefitari** first then my domain name **autun.hom** and then alias **nefitari**. You can select of your own, hostname.abc.net or hostname.home.lan etc. but remember changing to this file need to restart your server and then login. **Restart is must**

### **Now install BIND9**

```
 sudo apt-get install bind9
```

After installation just configure the below files step by step

- Named.conf.options
- Named.conf.local
- /etc/resolv.conf

**Now configure file named.conf.options**
This file is use for DNS IPs It mean that your server must connect to some DNS outside. When you buy domain name from ISP’s they normally gives you their own DNS IPs. You can use open DNS IPs of google or so. In my case I am using my own ISP DNS IPs.

```
 sudo nano /etc/bind/named.conf.options
 forwarders {
 # Give here your ISP DNS IP’s
192.168.1.1;    # gateway or router   
182.176.39.23;
182.176.18.13;
68.87.76.178;
  };
```

***Save the file and exit***using control x press y and overwrite the file

**Now edit the file named.conf.local**
This is the file in which we define forward zones and reverse zones. It means that when we enter domain name it will translate it into IP address and when we enter IP address it will simply convert it into name.

```
sudo nano /etc/bind/named.conf.local
```

will show:

```
# Our forward zone
zone "autun.hom" {
 type master;
 file "/etc/bind/zones/db.autun.hom";
 };

# Our reverse Zone 
# Server IP 192.168.1.5 
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/zones/db.192";
 };
```

***Save the file and exit***using control x press y and overwrite the file

Now we will make these two database files **db.autun.hom** and **db.192** in zones folder

First make the directory zones in /etc/bind/

```
  sudo mkdir /etc/bind/zones
```

Before making files let me clear you that I have different devices

**Devices       IPs**

- **Server itself**    192.168.1.5
- **Gateway**          192.168.1.1
- **Win7pc**       192.168.1.50

Now in zones directory we will create two files first **db.autun.hom**. I am just copying the **db.local** already present in **/etc/bind** folder to zones folder by changing its name to **db.autun.hom**.
I will put these IP’s in my db.autun.hom file. Let’s start

```
sudo cp /etc/bind/db.local  /etc/bind/zones/db.autun.hom
```

Now use the command below to edit the file

```
sudo nano /etc/bind/zones/db.autun.hom

 ;
 ; BIND data file for local loopback interface
 ;
 $TTL    604800
 @       IN      SOA     nefitari.autun.hom. webuser.autun.hom. (
                          2         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
  ;
autun.hom.      IN  NS  nefitari.autun.hom.
autun.hom.      IN  A   192.168.1.5
   ;@               IN  A   127.0.0.1
   ;@               IN  AAAA    ::1
nefitari            IN  A   192.168.1.5
gateway         IN  A   192.168.1.1
win7pc          IN  A   192.168.1.50
www     IN  CNAME   autun.hom.
```

**Save it and exit**

- **Webuser.autun.hom.** is the email who will access name server. You can
  write any name instead webuser like admin, root or host master etc.
- **Autun.hom.** is my NS means name server
- **Autun.hom**.changing to IP 192.168.1.5
- **@ IN A 127.0.0.1 and AAAA  ::1** can be comment out you should not need
  it because db.local is already present in /etc/bind it is just a copy
  of that file. So no need you can delete it
- Changing **Nefitari** to IP 192.168.1.5
- **Gateway** to IP 192.168.1.1
- **Win7pc** you can name your windows PCs or Linux Clients to any name but
  remember IP of that client must correctly be inserted into file. In
  my case I gave IP of windows PC 192.168.1.50
- Last, I am using **CNAME** means canonical name it is just an alias to
  nefitari. Means that you can access your server by entering
  www.autun.hom instead nefitari.autun.hom . You can omit this or
  comment it. It is just up to you.

Now create reverse lookup zone file

```
sudo cp /etc/bind/db.127    /etc/bind/zones/db.192
```

Now use the command below to edit the file

```
sudo nano /etc/bind/zones/db.192

   ;
   ; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
   ;
   $TTL    604800
   @       IN      SOA     nefitari.autun.hom. webuser.autun.hom. (
                          2         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
   ;
        IN  NS  nefitari.
1   IN  PTR gateway.autun.hom.
5   IN  PTR nefitari.autun.hom.
50  IN  PTR win7pc.autun.hom.
```

**Save it and exit**

Now when you are done with your zone file you have to check it whether it is working correctly or not by entering the command below for forward zone file

```
named-checkzone autun.hom /etc/bind/zones/db.autun.hom
zone autun.hom /IN: loaded serial   2
Ok
```

Now check the reverse zone file

```
named-checkzone autun.hom /etc/bind/zones/db.192
zone autun.hom /IN: loaded serial   2
Ok
```

**If the output of your named-checkzone is same as above then it is working fine otherwise you made some mistake in file.**

Now edit the file resolv.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver      192.168.1.5
domain      autun.hom
search      autun.hom
```

Enter the following lines into to your resolv.conf file and save it

**Restart the bind**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 restart
```

After bind start check your setting in log file

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

it must not have any error in the log

## **Checking forward zones**

```
host –l autun.hom
```

Output should like this

```
 autun.hom name server nefitari.autun.hom.
 autun.hom has address 192.168.1.5
 gateway.autun.hom has address 192.168.1.1
 nefitari.autun.hom has address 192.168.1.5
 win7pc.autun.hom has address 192.168.1.50
```

Now use **NSLOOKUP**

```
nslookup autun.hom
```

OUTPUT

```
Server: 192.168.1.5
Address: 192.168.1.5#53

Name: autun.hom
Address: 192.168.1.5
```

Use **DIG**

```
 dig gateway.autun.hom

 ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35612
 ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

 ;; QUESTION SECTION:
 ;gateway.autun.hom         IN  A

 ;; ANSWER SECTION:
 gateway.autun.hom      604800  IN  A   192.168.1.1

 ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
 Autun.hom.     604800  IN      NS  nefitari.autun.hom. 

 ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
 Nefitari.autun.hom.    604800  IN      A   192.168.1.5

 ;; Query time: 12 msec
 ;; SERVER: 192.168.1.5#53(192.168.1.5)
 ;; WHEN: Thu Aug 8 01:56:25 2013
 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 90
```

Output should similar to the above, check **status: NOERROR** means it is resolving check **ANSWER SECTION:** gateway.autun.hom is resolved into 192.168.1.1

## **Checking reverse zone**

```
 host 192.168.1.1
```

Output

```
 1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer gateway.autun.hom
```

**If it gives you an error like below**

```
 host 1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

This means that you made some mistake in **/etc/bind/named.conf.local** file in reverse zone
If your server IP is **192.168.1.5** then your reverse zone looks like this

```
zone "**1.168.192**.in-addr.arpa" {
 correct ip reversing
};
```

Sometime people made mistake in reversing the ip like (just an example)

```
zone "**0.168.192**.in-addr.arpa" {
incorrect ip reversing
};
```

Use **NSLOOKUP**

```
nslookup 192.168.1.1

Server: 192.168.1.5
Address: 192.168.1.5#53

1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa    name=gateway.autun.hom
```

*If you get NXDOMAIN or SERVFAIL like errors  it means that one of your zone file is not working correctly*

Now you can **ping ubuntu.com** or **dig ubuntu.com** for the first time it will take **several** miliseconds to resolve the name ubuntu.com but when you run it **second** time it will take **1, 2 or 3 seconds normally form 1 to 10 mili seconds** are normal and it means that your DNS is working properly

## **Configuring clients**

**windows side**

- open **network connections**
- select **change adapter settings**
- select **properties**
- select **internet protocol version IPv4**

and here give the IP address (in my case it is 192.168.1.50 have you remember win7pc)

- **IP address** 192.168.1.50
- **Subnet Mask** 255.255.255.0
- **Default Gateway** 192.168.1.1
- **primary DNS** 192.168.1.5 (my new BIND DNS server ip)
- in the same window select **Advance**
- select **DNS tab**
- Type in the text box below here In **DNS Suffix for this
  connection:autun.hom**
- click **ok**
- click on **validate setting upon exit**
- click ok

and you are done with it open CMD

```
ping gateway
```

it must gives you some replies

similarly

```
ping 192.168.1.1 or 5
```

it must gives you some replies

**Test Your Server to Outside World**

Now you can ping ubuntu.com or dig ubuntu.com for the first time it will take several miliseconds to resolve the name ubuntu.com but when you run it second time, it will take form 1 to 10 mili seconds, its normal time and it means that your DNS is working properly
Configuring clients

**windows side**

open network connections
select change adapter settings
select properties
select internet protocol version IPv4

and here give the IP address (in my case it is 192.168.1.50 have you remember win7pc)

**IP address** 192.168.1.50

**Subnet Mask** 255.255.255.0

**Default Gateway** 192.168.1.1

**primary DNS** 192.168.1.5 (my new BIND DNS server ip)

**select Advance** (in the same window)

select **DNS** tab

Type in the text box below here In DNS Suffix for this connection:autun.hom

click **ok**

click on validate setting upon exit

click **ok**

and you are done with it open **CMD**

**Code:**

```
 ping gateway
```

it must gives you some replies

similarly

**Code:**

```
 ping 192.168.1.1 or 5
```

it must gives you some replies
you can use **NSLOOKUP**
**Code:**

```
 nslookup gateway
```

**LINUX CLIENTS**

**Code:**

```
 sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

type the following lines

**Code:**

```
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Now restart Network Deamons

**Code:**

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

to force client renew IP command

**Code:**

```
 sudo dhclient -r
```

Now obtain fresh IP:

**Code:**

```
 sudo dhclient
```

If you are running DHCP server on your Network then enter the domain name and name server in dhcpd.conf file; for example I have DNS server named nefitari.autun.hom and IP address is 192.168.1.5 like as under

**Code:**

```
 option domain-name "nefitari.autun.hom";
 option domain-name-server  192.168.1.5;
```

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2166260)

Comment: It is a shame that this page has 3726 uniq views and the answer has only one upvote. If it was helpful to you, upvote it!

Comment: This answer is correct except for the part about editing /etc/resolv.conf. Since Ubuntu 12.04 you don't edit that file by hand but configure resolvconf to do so. Set RESOLVCONF=yes in /etc/default/bind9 to cause BIND 9 named to register its local listen address 127.0.0.1 with resolvconf when it starts. Make sure that /etc/resolv.conf is a symbolic link to `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.

Comment: syslog errors - `(network unreachable) resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:3::42#53` Are from bind trying to resolve queries recursively using ipv6. Editing `/etc/default/bind9` and using `OPTIONS="-u bind -4"` fixes it. More info: http://serverfault.com/questions/77325/unreachable-resolving-domain

Comment: I just got the setup with Ubuntu server 16.04 and it still works. The Serverguide tutorial on DNS is a nightmare compared to this explanation. However, I had to correct one *error* in the listings: in the file `db.192` before `IN NS nefitari.` is a `@` missing. Also I had to add the FQDN, so my **working** line looked like this `@ IN NS nefitari.autun.hom.` I ignored the resolv.conf section and followd the advice from jdthood. The link was already there from the default server installation.

Comment: Two items are still open 1) How to configure a linux client with static IP. Do I need to add `domain autun.hom` in /etc/hosts or is `dns-nameservers 192.168.1.5`in `/etc/network/interfaces` enough? If not why? 2) Linux and windows clients work fine, On the server itself `ping mylatop` fails, but `ping mylaptop.autun.hom` works. It there something missing in the description?

Comment: @fotanus I think it's because it's so long that people forgot to scroll back up to upvote\

Answer (score 1):

The answer is just an addition to the great description above.

**Troubleshooting tip**

Be very careful with the many '.' in the configuration files as each one is important. A single missing '.' can stop the DNS server from working. You should not count on clear error messages.

I learned its good practice to use a more telling serial number. Its very important to increment the serial number every time the setup is modified, e.g. new entries being added. If its not incremented a secondary DNS will fail to synchronize the new settings. The suggested format is `YYYYMMDDss`, where `ss` is the "old" serial number. So when incrementing, you should increment `ss` by +1 *and* set the date to the current date. 
I found this very helpful in troubleshooting the setup. In the syslog you clearly see the date and serial of the used file.

In Ubuntu 16.04 changing resolv.conf is deprecated. As [jdthood](https://askubuntu.com/users/29569/jdthood) writes in his comment replace the step with the following procedure:
 - Change /etc/default/bind9: the new will should look like this:

```
   # run resolvconf?
   RESOLVCONF=yes

   # startup options for the server
   OPTIONS="-u bind"

   # use this when you have trouble with IPV6
   #OPTIONS="-u bind -4"
```

see comment from [not-a-patch](https://askubuntu.com/users/136803/not-a-patch) for the IPV6 issues.

- put a symlink of /etc/resolv.conf into /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

  ```
   cd /etc
   sudo ln -s /etc/resolv.conf /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
  ```

**Offline Setup**

The setup is exactly the same, and even a bit easier, since you can just skip the forwarding sections. They do not have to be present, so there is no need to edit the `/etc/bind/names.con.options`.

**Class-B Networks**

There are a few minor changes required to make this work for class-B networks (before there are comments, there is no reason why a local network , even at home, could not be a class-B instead of a class-C network). In this example I use the network number 172.20.x.x. (I think the formal notation is 172.20.0.0. for more info google rfc1918).

Use the description from the first answer, replace all IPs 192.168.x.x with 172.20.x.x, use for the server IP 172.20.0.100 and modify the files as follows:

- the name of the file `db.192` becomes `db.172`.
- the file `named.conf.local` gets a different reverse zone section:

  ```
  zone "20.172.in-addr.arpe" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/zones/db.172";
  }
  ```
- The reverse zones file changes to:

  ```
  ;
  ; BIND reverse data file for 172.20.x.x
  ;
  $TTL    604800
  @       IN      SOA     nefitari.autun.hom. webuser.autun.hom. (
               2017022102         ; more intuitive serial YYYYMMDDss, here ss=02
                   604800         ; Refresh
                    86400         ; Retry
                  2419200         ; Expire
                   604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL

  ; note: the '@'was missing from in the initial description
  @       IN  NS  nefitari.autun.hom.    

  100.0   IN  PTR nefitari.autun.hom. 
  121.0   IN  PTR client1.autun.hom.
  130.0   IN  PTR client2.autun.hom.
  33.0    IN  PTR client3.autun.hom.
  ```

The rest is the same.

Hope its useful for someone.

Comment: Does this work if you are wanting to use both 172.16 and 172.20 addresses?

Comment: @kojow7. Very good question. I do not know but to find out you could either check just to include a second zone and second reverse file. Its easy to test with the nslookup command. Or, maybe the better was, just use a Netmask that includes both 172.16. and 172.20. The netmask would not be as simple as 255.255.0.0 but contain other numbers beside 0 and 255, but on the net you can find tutorials how to figure that out in case you do not know already. In case you solved it please consider to post it here for the benefit of others.