# How to host a website using Ubuntu 13.04 on my local machine

Tags: networking, server, dns, hosting

[How do I do a complete BIND9 DNS Server Configuration with a hostname?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330148/how-do-i-do-a-complete-bind9-dns-server-configuration-with-a-hostname/331568#331568?newreg=07487e495c144296beede9e2e84f629e)

Thank You so much for this wonderful answer. Although the talk here had been more on the lines of setting up a home based server to be used locally.

It will be helpful if anyone can list out changes required if I want to host a website globally, so anyone anywhere can open it.

Thanks for all the help the community provides :)

Comment: a website that should be "up" all the time need your local machine to run 24hours a day and 7days a week.... maybe you should think of paying a hoster?
its (nearly) no difference between a "webserver" that runs locally and one that runs globally - beside the security needs and (maybe) the traffic. usually a internet connection is asynchron, that means that your upload bandwidth is smaller then your download.