# can I use bind9 as a DNS to resolve to an external IP?

Tags: network-manager, dns, ip, bind, domain-server

Question says it all. I have a digital ocean IP address and I want to know if I can use bind9 to resolve a registered domain on a completely different network/IP? If not, what can I use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sure you can.

for your case you have just to insert the external IP in forwarders
 in the /etc/bind/named.conf.options file

```
 Sudo nano /etc/bind/named.conf.options
 forwarders {
 # Give here your IP
  };
```

Please read this to learn the full configuration of bind9 in Ubuntu. [How do I do a complete BIND9 DNS Server Configuration with a hostname?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330148/how-do-i-do-a-complete-bind9-dns-server-configuration-with-a-hostname)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to be able to help