# Ubuntu DNS server working, but getting errors in syslog

Tags: networking, server, dns

it's my first question to the forum here, so please go easy on me. I'm a Linux newbie and I experimented with setting up my own Ubuntu server (server name : araliya, domain: autun.hom, IP: 192.168.1.99). I setup everything and installed bind9 to setup a DNS server using the tutorial posted here ([How do I do a complete BIND9 DNS Server Configuration with a hostname?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330148/how-do-i-do-a-complete-bind9-dns-server-configuration-with-a-hostname)).

Everything went actually very well, until the step at the very end, when I had to check whether the DNS server is working. When I gave the following command, I got a good output.

```
> named-checkzone autun.hom /etc/bind/zones/db.autun.hom
  zone autun.hom /IN: loaded serial   2
  Ok
```

However, when I did the same thing for my reverse DNS lookup I got a slightly different answer.

```
> named-checkzone autun.hom /etc/bind/zones/db.192
  zone autun.hom /IN: loaded serial   1
  Ok
```

The tutorial said that the output of "named-checkzone" should be the same for forward and reverse lookup zones. But the "loaded serial" value I get is different between the two answers.

When I followed all the other tests including, dig, hostname, nslookup, I get good output. In fact, my DNS server looks like it's working. When I checked the syslog, however, I get lots of errors:

```
May 10 20:09:04 araliya named[1026]: validating @0x7f1314706200: . NS: got insecure          response; parent indicates it should be secure
May 10 20:09:04 araliya named[1026]: error (insecurity proof failed) resolving  './NS/IN': 192.168.1.1#53
May 10 20:09:12 araliya named[1026]: validating @0x7f1314706200: . NS: got insecure response; parent indicates it should be secure
May 10 20:09:12 araliya named[1026]: error (insecurity proof failed) resolving './NS/IN': 192.168.1.1#53
May 10 20:09:13 araliya named[1026]: error (network unreachable) resolving './NS/IN': 2001:7fe::53#53
May 10 20:09:24 araliya named[1026]: validating @0x7f1314706200: . NS: got insecure response; parent indicates it should be secure
May 10 20:09:24 araliya named[1026]: error (insecurity proof failed) resolving './NS/IN': 192.168.1.1#53
```

The weird thing is that all hostnames are being resolved correctly but it looks like I may have made a mistake somewhere. Can someone help me pinpoint where the error is?

Answer (score 7):

These error messages are related to dnssec. Remove or comment out all the lines in `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` that start with `dnssec` and restart bind9.

The best explanation for what's going on that I could find is [here](http://dotat.at/tmp/arm97/Bv9ARM.ch04.html#id2571882):

> When the validator receives a response from an unsigned zone that has
>   a signed parent, it must confirm with the parent that the zone was
>   intentionally left unsigned. It does this by verifying, via signed and
>   validated NSEC/NSEC3 records, that the parent zone contains no DS
>   records for the child.
>
> If the validator can prove that the zone is insecure, then the
>   response is accepted. However, if it cannot, then it must assume an
>   insecure response to be a forgery; it rejects the response and logs an
>   error.
>
> The logged error reads "insecurity proof failed" and "got insecure
>   response; parent indicates it should be secure". (Prior to BIND 9.7,
>   the logged error was "not insecure". This referred to the zone, not
>   the response.)

Comment: your answer guide me to the right solution. **dnssec-validation no;** on **/etc/bind/named.conf.options**

Comment: It seemed to me like turning off dnssec was a bad idea, so I added google's dns server to `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` and commented out the dns servers that were throwing errors (namely comcast's)

Answer (score -1):

Add below line to your "/etc/default/bind9"

as below:

```
# startup options for the server
OPTIONS="-u bind -4"
```

Comment: could you describe what it does? I know I could RTFM...