# I have no SOA how to edit the db.domain file

Tags: wireless, dns, bind, domain-server

I am in a private network having 192.168.1.0/24 . I have a wireless router, i am providing wifi hotspot to my users with wireless router and i have 100 users in the network. I want to provide name to my webserver's ip. for that I selected bind. But i am not connected to any ISP's(i haven't any internet facility) so what ip i have to give in the forward section of named.conf.options.

and what configuration i have to put in db.domain file i don't know about SOA?
my webserver's ip is 192.168.1.29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the forward section you can keep your DNS server IP,  or just set some Generic ISP IP such as `4.4.4.4` or `8.8.8.8`. Indeed the forwards will not affect your internal DNS this is used when caching to the outer domains.

In order to understand bind9 with ubuntu it's better to read more about before starting your configuration.

you can read the official documentation from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto).
Another great tutorial can get from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Please refer to this link [How do I do a complete BIND9 DNS Server Configuration with a hostname?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330148/how-do-i-do-a-complete-bind9-dns-server-configuration-with-a-hostname) you can find your needs in detail

Comment: actually i provided the wifi hotspot with netgear router and i am running only one server i haven't any internet connections so how i can give forwarding servers as 8.8.8.8

Comment: It's fake this will not be used if you don't have external connection. this is used for caching when connecting to external, but since you are not using Internet this will not affect your system, It's same if you just put your IP or any other IP

Comment: i want use webserver as a dns server also because i have only one server.

Comment: @ashok it's the same

Comment: my whole network is 192.168.1.0/24  my server getting the dhcp ip  from the hotspot which is created in router. please guide me the configuration for dns server with bind. please.

Comment: read the links i provided you above

Comment: but in the digitalocean site it's saying primary dns,secondary dns i am confused with that.

Comment: forget about secondary just work for the primary

Comment: then what about the SOA in the place of SOA he given the secondary dns. something like  admin.nyc3.example.com.

Comment: don't write it, everything that deals with secondary can just emit it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24248/discussion-between-ashok-and-maythux).