# painfuilly slow windows clients using bind on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, dns

I'm very new to Ubuntu (though I've installed 14.04 server a dozen times now) and Linux and I'm trying to replace my Win2003 server with Ubuntu 14.04 server. I have a brand new shiny HP Gen8 box and a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 server install with only the basics installed. I followed the step by step in the post " [How do I do a complete BIND9 DNS Server Configuration with a hostname?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330148/how-do-i-do-a-complete-bind9-dns-server-configuration-with-a-hostname) " and everything appears to work as it should, but when I connect a Windows7 client it is extremely slow. I'm talking 2 - 3 minutes to load a page. once it loads the initial page however, everything moves along as it should. but once you close the browser (IE11) or restart, it's back to 2 - 3 minute load time. what am I missing?